# What is the regex command to extract values within a parentheses + static text?

Tags: regex, extract, parentheses

I've trimmed enough of my file to extract a certain value + static text that follows with the value.

```
Test Listing CDO (56 Custom Object Records)
```

I'll like to grab `56 Custom Object Records` from that line. I've tried `(?<=\).+?(?=\Custom Object Records))` which does not seem to work.

Comment: command is usuerly one of `find`, `search` or `match` depening on platerform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this regex ([pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre)):

```
\(\K[^\)]+
```

Ex:

```
$ grep -oP '\(\K[^\)]+' file
56 Custom Object Records
```

https://regex101.com/r/2cx8lC/1